# Can be PersistentEntity state type a trait?

Tags: scala, lagom

All examples uses one case class as PersistentEntity state with some property for chech state and use different actions. Something like

```
override def behavior: Behavior = {
  case state if state.isEmpty  => initial
  case state if !state.isEmpty => postAdded
}
```

Can be used different case classes of one trait for different states? For example:

```
sealed trait OrderState
case object UnitializedOrder
case class OpenedOrder(items: List[String])
case object ClosedOrder

override def behavior: Behavior = {
  case UnitializedOrder  => initOrderActions
  case OpenedOrder => openedOrderActions
  case ClosedOrder => skipCommandsAction
}
```

I saw some problems like

1. Handler types

   CommandHandler = PartialFunction[(Command, CommandContext[Any], State), Persist]
   EventHandler = PartialFunction[(Event, State), State]

uses State (trait), so needed class casting

2. Serialization for every state subtype for snapshoting.

Or there is something more scary?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand the question.

Comment: type Behavior defined as State => Actions, so can be State defined as trait but not a concrete class?

Comment: Actions() is a part of PersistenceEntity instance, so it defined as `extends (State=>Actions)` (has link to State type from super class), but not a part of State, so, I can't understand can be the State concrete class or may be a trait too.
Command=>Event function is the same for all instances, and `state` can be a parameter, what is a reason for creating the same function instance for every PersistenceEntity instance.